# Reason behind the transformation of a single columned dataframe to a vector after subsetting

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a single columned data frame structure. Based on a condition, I am subsetting the data frame during run time. I have observed that the data frame is being converted into a vector after subsetting. I have achieved the data frame structure back using the `as.data.frame()` function.

```
# random generation of the values    
df <- data.frame(a=sample(1:1000,100))
#checking the class of the object
class(df)
#dimensions
dim(df)
#[1] 100   1
#subsetting the data with a random value present in the df, here 547
df_sub <- df[-df$a==547,]
# checking the subset dataset class
class(df_sub)
#[1] "integer"
```

I would like to know how to preserve the data frame structure without explicitly using the `as.data.frame()` function.

Comment: [Hadley's `tibble`s](https://github.com/hadley/tibble/) are more consistent about keeping their class, which can be helpful if you're working programmatically and aren't sure when you might need `drop = FALSE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R often tries to simplify objects after subsetting. If this is not desired, you can use the drop=FALSE argument to prevent such simplifications:

```
df_sub <- df[-df$a==547,, drop=FALSE]

> class(df_sub)
[1] "data.frame"
```

The drop=FALSE is also available for matrices:

```
myMat <- matrix(1:10, 5)

> class(myMat[, 1])
[1] "integer"
> 
> class(myMat[, 1, drop=FALSE])
[1] "matrix"
> 
> class(myMat[1, ])
[1] "integer"
> 
> class(myMat[1, , drop=FALSE])
[1] "matrix"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subset`:

```
df_sub <- subset(df, a != 547)
class(df_sub) #data.frame
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the following example, the class of the subset is still a `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(1:1000,100), b = sample(1:1000,100))
class(df)
#data.frame
df_sub <- df[-df$a == 706,]
class(df_sub)
#data.frame
```

In your case you have a 100x1 data.frame, which will automatically be interpreted as a vector. In my example, it is still a `data.frame`.

When you want to keep the `data.frame`, you had to use:

```
df_sub <- subset(df, a != 706)
```

Regards,

J_F